# How to send input to hidden program c++?

Tags: c++, input, hidden, send

So my question is how to send some comands or input from one (c++) program to another if hi is on hidden mode? For example I want to open some text file in notepad with function WinExec("notepad", 0); and than want to print conetent of file, I make handle to that file, make sendinput with CTRL+P, and the window of printig show up,.... I want to make all that proces hidden from user, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to do it. You can open notepad on a separate desktop. If you run notepad with SW_HIDDEN it would also not show the window, and then you can use `windows hooks` to hook the creation of print window and ShowWindow() it to hidden.

But why all the hassle? If you don't need notepad's UI, why not just print the file yourself?

Comment: thnx... I just put notepad and printing for easy example, what I have to do is more advanced things, like sending bunch of commands to program, all in hidden mode